# Valgrind - memory leaks

Tags: valgrind

Need to find memory leaks in code. 
Does valgrind indicate memory leaks as they happen during run time?
How can I integrate Valgrind into my code base that runs on proprietry tool chain.

Comment: what is lang do you use?

Comment: What OS are you using, And how proprietry is your toolchain ?

Comment: LINUX. GNU EABI toolchain